# Natural Parameter Space of an Exponential Family is a convex set (Proof)?

Tags: integration, statistics, inequality, bayesian, exponential-distribution

A natural parameter family is defined as follows
$$p(x|\eta) = h(x) \exp(\eta T(x) + A(\eta))$$
where 
T: sufficient statistics 
A: log partition function.

We want to prove that the natural parameter space $\mathcal{N}$ given by $$\mathcal{N} = \left\{ \eta: \int(\exp(A(\eta))) < \infty \right\}$$ 
is convex.

The proof rests on holder inequality and is given [here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~jordan/courses/260-spring10/other-readings/chapter8.pdf). 
I am attaching a picture for a quick [reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kVSuA.png)
I have looked at the definition of holder [inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality). 
I am not really sure how the $1/\lambda$ and $1/1-\lambda$ are written in the denominator in eq 8.35 when applying the holder inequality in the proof given.

Also in Eq 8.36 how is the $e^{\lambda n^T T(x)}$ is discared for the integral.

Please help in explaining these things?

Answer (score -1):

That looks like a mistake in print. Ideally, the $1/\lambda$ should be in the power for $\exp(\lambda\eta T(x))^{1/\lambda}$ where $p=1/\lambda$ in the Holder's inequality.

Also, it's not $\eta^T$ ($\eta$ raised to the power T), but $\eta^\mathrm{'}T$ which is just the multiplication of 2 matrices.